# Babylonian solution to general cubic

Tags: polynomials

**Problem:** Otto Neugebauer believes that the Babylonians were quite capable of reducing the general cubic equation to the "normal form" $n^3 + n^2 = c$, although there is as yet no evidence that they actually did do this. Show how such a reduction might be made.

*Eves Remark:* Take the cubic in $x$ with unit leading coefficient and subject it to a linear transformation of the type $x = y+m$. Determine $m$ so that the resulting cubic in $y$ lacks the linear term.

*External remark:* One can bring every cubic equation of the form $x^3+ax^2+bx+c = 0$ into the form $n^3 + n^2 = p$. The transformation to $u^3+qu^2 = r$ comes from the substitution $x=u+s$ and $s$ can be determined from a quadratic equation [my comment: how is this helpful? What quadratic equation exactly?]. If $u^3 + qu^2 = r$ is divided by $q^3$, then $(\frac{u}{q})^3 + (\frac{u}{q})^2 = \frac{r}{q^3}$.

*My remark:* Concerning Eves' remark, I cannot determine a satisfactory value for $m$. I end up with a very messy expression, just like I do when I try to use the advice in the "external remark." If I make the substitution $x=u+s$ and expand the general cubic, I get the following: $s^3+s^2(3u+a)+s(3u^2+2au+b)+u^3+au^2+bu+c=0$. This does not seem to be of much help; the remark about being able to solve for $s$ using a quadratic equation would be helpful if this were further explicated, but I cannot find a satisfactory value for $s$. Any ideas about how to solve the originally stated problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $x=u+s$ into $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ yields

$$u^3+(3s+a)u^2+(3s^2+2as+b)u+(s^3+as^2+bs+c)=0\;.\tag{1}$$

In line with usual naming conventions I’m thinking of $u$ as the variable and $s$ as a constant that I’m going to choose.  Specifically, I want to choose $s$ so that $3s^2+2as+b=0$, thereby eliminating the first-degree term in $u$. That is, if we set

$$s=\frac{-2a\pm\sqrt{4a^2-12b}}6=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-3b}}3\;,$$

then $(1)$ becomes

$$u^3+(3s+a)u^2+(s^3+as^2+bs+c)=0\;.$$

Setting $q=3s+a$ and $r=-(s^3+as^2+bs+c)$ reduces $(1)$ to $u^3+qu^2=r$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The coefficient of $s^1$ is $3u^2+2au+b$. Now, for what values of *u* is that coefficient $0$ ?

Comment: The values for which $u$ gives a coefficient of 0 are $\frac{-2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2-12b}}{6}$. But how does this help me solve for $s$ or help me with the original problem for that matter?

Comment: **Update:** Brian's approach above answered my question.